# Android Changing The Modified Date For Files Exported To Local Storage

Tags: java, android, file

I am creating an android app and added an option to save media such as images and videos, I need to be able to change the modified date of the file to whatever the current date and time are. I have been using the File method to save files. I have seen that this is a known issue with the .setLastModified() method in Android but am unable to find any other solution to this problem. This method doesn't seem to do anything at least on my device (Google Pixel 2). It will just have the original date.

I have even tried doing some "dirty method" by using the RandomFileAccess() method (I'll show the code below) But with no luck.

```
File rootPath = new   File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile(), "imageAlbum");
    if(!rootPath.exists()) {
        rootPath.mkdirs();
    }

File localFile = new File(rootPath,filename.toLowerCase());
```

Then I use firebase and the .getFile() method.

This is what I mean by a "dirty" method.

```
RandomAccessFile raf = null;
try {
    raf = new RandomAccessFile(rootPath + "/" + finalFilename.toLowerCase(), "rw");
long length = raf.length();
    raf.setLength(length + 1);
    raf.setLength(length);
    raf.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}               }

localFile.setLastModified(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

But again with no luck.

EDIT:

Here is the code I am using for firebase.

```
String finalFilename = filename;
storageReference.getFile(localFile).addOnCompleteListener(new  OnCompleteListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {

    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        localFile.setLastModified(System.currentTimeMillis());
    {
```

I have tried using the ".setLastModified" method before and after calling the firebase methods.

Comment: I don't see any usage of Firebase in your code samples. Please include that part also to clarify the context in which Firebase is part of the issue.

Comment: sorry, the firebase code is now added.